# What's the best way to share memory between two shared libraries (macOS plugins)?

Tags: c++, macos, plugins, shared-libraries

I have two shared libraries that need to share objects between each other. That means I need to share memory from one shared library to the other and vice versa.
Obviously, I need to use `extern` declarations. However, if either of the libraries is not loaded, trying to access external functions/variables will cause crash.

So now I'm thinking of extracting common/shareable objects into a third, separate shared library which those two should link to. However I have those shared libraries as macOS plugins and that means that each plugin will have its' own copy of common shared library. How one can approach this?